# What code would I put in HTML to apply search filters?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have provided an example of what it'd look like below. I'm trying to code a (rather nsfw) search table for people to use. I'm not sure how i'd code the filters for the search. I want to either be able to search by name, use the filters, or if you have filters applied, then the search bar only searches for results inside of those filters. I am using HTML, JS, and CSS only!

[The Example Image (This is SFW)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9mTDl.jpg)

Please don't skip because of the reason that this is for an NSFW website..

Answer (score 0):

If you are using vanilla js, you can do a HTML with a form, and listen all the changes the form have when the user do click, [something like this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/elements):

```html
<form id="my-form">
  <input type="text" name="username">
  <input type="text" name="full-name">
  <input type="password" name="password">
  <button type="button" id="search">Search!</button>
</form>
```

```js
const searchButton = document.getElementById("search")
const inputs = document.getElementById("my-form").elements;
const inputByIndex = inputs[0];
const inputByName = inputs["username"];

searchButton.addEventListener("click", functionWhichIWillCommunicateWithTheServer)
```

with the form values you can use something like fetch to communicate with your server.

```js
// The parameters of the endpoint are comming from the form
function functionWhichIWillCommunicateWithTheServer() {
  fetch("someEndpointWithTheirParameters")
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => console.log(data))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#myTable tr").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
});
</script>
```